# Verify this identity: $\sin x/(1 - \cos x) = \csc x + \cot x$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

Verify this identity $\frac{\sin {x}} {1 - \cos {x}}\ =  \csc x + \cot x$  I got the left side to $\frac{1-\cos x} {\csc x}$, but I can't get any farther.  Am I on the right path?  Can I get some help?

Comment: you have done the left side wrongly....check your calculations!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right-hand side can be rewritten as

$$\csc{x} + \cot{x} = \frac{1}{\sin{x}} + \frac{\cos{x}}{\sin{x}} = \frac{1 + \cos{x}}{\sin{x}}$$

Multiplying the left side top and bottom by $1 + \cos{x}$, we find that

$$\frac{\sin{x}}{1 - \cos{x}} = \frac{\sin{x}(1 + \cos{x})}{1 - \cos^2{x}} = \frac{\sin{x}(1 + \cos{x})}{\sin^2{x}} = \frac{1 + \cos{x}}{\sin{x}}$$

Answer (score 2):

As $\displaystyle\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1,$

$\implies \displaystyle\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x=(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)$

$\implies \displaystyle\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}=\frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x}=\frac1{\sin x}+\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}=\csc x+\cot x$

Comment: @KKendall, how about this one?

Answer (score 0):

To prove sin x/1-cos x = cosec x + cot x
We know that,
Sin^2 x = 1- cos^2
So from RHS we get,
Cosec x+cot x
=1/sin x + cos x/sin x
So taking LCM,
We get,
1+cos x/sin x
Now multiply both numerator and denominator by sin x to get denominator as sin^2 x
We get,
(1+cos x)(sin x)/sin^2 x
Now we can write sin^2 x as 1- cos^2 x
So, we get 
(1+cos x)(sin x)/1-cos^2 x
(1+cos x)(sin x)/(1+cos x)(1-cos x)
applying a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)
so by cancellation
We get sin x/1-cosx=cosec x+cot x

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please take a look at [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn about typesetting your post to make it easier to read.