# Prove or disprove $\frac{\sqrt{1+\tan x}}{\cot x} = \frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}$

Tags: trigonometry

I have tried to prove the identity \begin{equation}
\frac{\sqrt{1+\tan x}}{\cot x} = \frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}
\end{equation}
by $t$-substitution but seem not to work. Please don't solve(don`t post the answer on this site) this question for me just try it and give me hints on how I should go about it. Or if you like you can post but I wanted to try using some hints that you would give first.

Comment: Counterexample: Take $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$. LHS gives $\sqrt2$ while RHS gives $\sqrt2+1$

Comment: I guess, [this identity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514229/verify-this-identity-sin-x-1-cos-x-csc-x-cot-x) makes more sense.

Comment: I was argued against in class because initialy I plugged in pi/4 but our tutor proved some incompetence to me and competence to the class and he said you don`t prove identities using angles. Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: You can't prove an identity by plugging in one angle, but you can certainly disprove a proposed identity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x=\pi/4$ we have: $$\frac{\sqrt{1+1}}{1}=\sqrt{2}$$ on the left, but $$\frac{1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}{1/\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}+1$$ on the right.

These are not equivalent.

Comment: How do you get $\frac{\sqrt2+1}{\sqrt2}$ ?

Comment: Typo. I fixed it. @prasunbiswas

Answer (score 4):

As stated, equality is false. Letting $x=0$, the left hand side is $0$ while the right hand side is $1$.

Comment: $x=0$ would make $\cot(x)$ undefined.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas: The function is analytic around $0$ and has a removable singularity - note we may write it as $$\frac{\sin(x)\sqrt{1+\tan(x)}}{\cos(x)}.$$ If you strongly dislike removable singularities, then take $x=0.00001$.